# How to join html tables in R on top of each other?

Tags: r

Currently I have an R script that extracts data from a web page to html tables, I have three tables and I would like to know how to join or concatenate them, one on top of the other since at the moment the result gives me tables one next to the other and it does not serve me.

```
library(rvest)

urls.colombia.compra.microsoft <- paste0("https://colombiacompra.gov.co/tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra?page=", 
                               0:11, 
                               "&number_order=&state=&entity=&tool=IAD%20Software%20I%20-%20Microsoft&date_to_=%20&date_from_=")


base.colombia.compra.microsft <- purrr::map_df(urls.colombia.compra.microsoft, ~.x %>% read_html() %>% html_table())

base.colombia.compra.microsft

urls.colombia.compra.google <- paste0("https://colombiacompra.gov.co/tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra?page=", 
                               0:11, 
                               "&number_order=&state=&entity=&tool=IAD%20Software%20I%20-%20Google&date_to_=%20&date_from_=")

base.colombia.compra.google <- purrr::map_df(urls.colombia.compra.google, ~.x %>% read_html() %>% html_table())

base.colombia.compra.google

urls.colombia.compra.nube <- paste0("https://colombiacompra.gov.co/tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra?page=", 
                                      0:11, 
                                      "&number_order=&state=&entity=&tool=Nube%20Pública%20III&date_to_=%20&date_from_=")

base.colombia.compra.nube <- purrr::map_df(urls.colombia.compra.nube, ~.x %>% read_html() %>% html_table())

base.colombia.compra.nube

merge(base.colombia.compra.microsft, base.colombia.compra.google, by = "Orden de Compra")

union <- dplyr::full_join(dplyr::full_join(base.colombia.compra.microsft, base.colombia.compra.google, by = "Orden de Compra"), base.colombia.compra.nube, by = "Orden de Compra")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dplyr::bind_rows` to combine the three into one table with an `id` column to differentiate the three.

```
union <- dplyr::bind_rows(base.colombia.compra.microsft, 
                          base.colombia.compra.google, 
                          base.colombia.compra.nube, .id = 'id')
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `rbindlist`

```
library(data.table)
union <- rbindlist(list(base.colombia.compra.microsft, 
                          base.colombia.compra.google, 
                          base.colombia.compra.nube), idcol = 'id')
```